# Matching bins up to shuffling

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Suppose a school purchased three bins of $n$ balls each, with each bin (labelled $1,2,3$ say) consisting of a different colour of balls, say red (1), green (2), and blue (3). On the first day the three bins were placed on the playground for children to play, and they emptied the bins. At the end of the day the custodian collects all of the balls and place them back into bins, without regard to whether the balls go in their original bins. Each bin has a capacity of $n$ and we assume that no ball is ever lost, so at the end of the day each bin contains $n$ balls of various colours. Every day the process is repeated: at the beginning of the day the three bins are emptied, and at the end of the day the custodian collects all of the balls and place them back into bins, without regard to colour.

The curious custodian records how many balls of each colour is in each bin. Indeed, he records a $3 \times 3$ integer matrix

$$\displaystyle A^{(k)} = (a_{ij}^{(k)})_{1 \leq i \leq j \leq 3}$$

where $a_{ij}^{(k)}$ is the number balls of colour $i$ in bin $j$ at the end of day $k$. Note that we may set

$$\displaystyle A^{(0)} = \begin{bmatrix} n & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & n \end{bmatrix}.$$

For an arbitrary $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ and an element $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_3$, the symmetric group on three letters, let $\sigma(A)$ denote the result by letting $\sigma$ act on the columns of $A$ (i.e., shuffling the columns of $A$ according to $\sigma$).

Aside from recording the matrices $A^{(k)}$ for each day $k$, the custodian also computes the *custodian ratio* $c(\ell_1, \ell_2)$ defined by

$$\displaystyle 3n c(\ell_1, \ell_2) =  \max_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_3}  \sum_{j=1}^3 \sum_{i=1}^3 \min \left(a_{ij}^{(\ell_1)}, \sigma(a_{ij}^{(\ell_2)}) \right) $$

where $0 \leq \ell_1 < \ell_2 \leq k$ and where $\sigma(a_{ij})$ is the $ij$-th entry of $\sigma(A)$. Note that for fixed $ij$ the summand corresponds to the number of balls of colour $i$ that are in bin $j$ on both the $\ell_1$-th and $\ell_2$-th days, after shuffling the bins by $\sigma$. The double sum then corresponds to the total number balls having the same colour in the same bin on both days, up to shuffling by $\sigma$. The max then takes the best possible way to shuffle. The factor of $3n$ in the front then gives us a genuine ratio.

My question is, for a given $n$, what is the largest number $m(n)$ of days such that the custodian ratio $c(\ell_1, \ell_2) \leq 2/3$ for all $0 \leq \ell_1 < \ell_2 \leq m(n)$? Clearly $m(n)$ is well-defined, since there are only finitely many possible matrices $A^{(k)}$ and so eventually, by the pigeonhole principle, two of the matrices must coincide which gives a custodian ratio of $1$. However, I suspect that $k(n)$ is very small, perhaps even independent of $n$.

Comment: Does the custodian put exactly $n$ balls in each bin?  Also, it is confusing to have $c(k)$, $c(k,\ell)$, and $c(\ell,k(n))$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will do some clean up.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but it seems that $m(n)$ is bounded by a constant independent of $n$ even is we were to remove the maximum from the definition of $c(l_1,l_2)$. Indeed, if $k,l$ are such that $A^{(k)}_{i,j}$ and $A^{(l)}_{i,j}$ differ by at most $\epsilon n$ for all $i,j$, then $c(k,l) \geq 1 - 100 \epsilon$. Such $k$ and $l$ are guaranteed to come up in the first $1/\epsilon^9$ steps by pigeonhole principle. It remains to set $\epsilon = 1/300$.